# How can i insert multiple rows each of which has an array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image][image]I need to insert data from multiple rows. And each of these rows has an array on the third column, Class. I want to insert it such that the data in the database will look like that shown on the MYSQL screenshot below. The error I am having is that the class column inserts a duplicate data instead.[image].

```
<script>
var rowCount = 1;
function addMoreRows(frm){
rowCount ++;
var inputer = '<div class="row rowCount'+rowCount+'"><div class="col-md-3">    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="highest_mark_obtainable[]"></div></div><div class="col-md-3"><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="class[]"><?php foreach($class_rows as $class_row){echo'<option value="'.$class_row['group'].'">'.$class_row['class'].'</option>';}?></select></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove row</button></div></div>';
    $('.gra-grp-row').append(inputer);
}
function removeRow(removeNum){
    $('.rowCount'+removeNum).remove();

}


</script>

Below is my model
public function create_subject(){
$subject = $this->input->post('subject');
$highest_mark_obtainable = $this->input->post('highest_mark_obtainable');
$classes[] = implode(',', $this->input->post('class'));

for($i = 0; $i < count($subject); $i++){
for($p = 0; $p < count($classes); $p++){
$new_subject = array(
'subject' => $subject[$i],
'highest_mark_obtainable' => $highest_mark_obtainable[$i],
'class' => $classes[$p],
'username' => $this->session->userdata('username')
);
$this->db->insert('subject', $new_subject);

}
}
return TRUE;
}
}


 Below is my controller

 public function create_subject(){
 $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
 if($this->input->is_ajax_request() && $this->input->post('ajax') == 1){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject[]', 'Subject',
 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[50]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('highest_mark_obtainable[]', 'Maximum          `enter code here`marks obtainable', 'trim|required|numeric');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'Class', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->output->set_status_header('400');
    echo '<span class="admin_validation_error" `enter code   here`style="color:#ff0000">'.validation_errors().'</span>';

    } else {

 if($this->subject_model->create_subject() == true){
 echo '<span class="validation_success" style="color:green; font-   weight:bolder">Well done! Subject(s) successfully created.</span>';
  }

        }

 }else{
    redirect('errors/not_found');
 }
 }     `

 BELOW IS THE FORM

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="Subject">Subject<span class="asterix"> *</span></label>           
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]" id=""    placeholder="Mathematics" value="">
 </div>

 </div><!--Subject-->
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="Highest mark obtainable">Maximum marks obtainable<span 
   `class="asterix"> *</span></label>  
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="highest_mark_obtainable[]"   
  id="" placeholder="100" value="">
</div>
</div><!--Highest mark obtainable-->
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Class">Classes that do subject<span class="asterix"> *</span> 
 </label>  <select class="form-control select2subjects" name="class[]"        `   `multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">
  <?php foreach ($class_rows as $class){
    echo '<option value="'.$class['class'].'">'.$class['class'].'</option>';
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div><!--class associated with subject-->
  <div class="col-md-2">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should really read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and specifically about the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (in short: You should not have more than one entry in a column, if that's the case split it into 2 tables and use a relationship)

Comment: `$this->input->post('class')` is an array of arrays?

Comment: remove second for and implode classes inside loop

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if your using Codeigniter 3 and im not sure if this function is exclusive to Codeginiter 3 

You could use the function in the query builder `$this->db->insert_batch()`

```
$data = array(
    array(
            'title' => 'My title',
            'name' => 'My Name',
            'date' => 'My date'
    ),
    array(
            'title' => 'Another title',
            'name' => 'Another Name',
            'date' => 'Another date'
    )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'),  ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

A further explanation here:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#inserting-data

Answer (score 0):

```
$classes = $this->input->post('class');

for($i = 0; $i < count($subject); $i++) {
    $new_subject = array(
    'subject' => $subject[$i],
    'highest_mark_obtainable' => $highest_mark_obtainable[$i],
    'class' => implode(',', $classes[$i]),
    'username' => $this->session->userdata('username')
    );
    $this->db->insert('subject', $new_subject);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138449/discussion-on-answer-by-carlos-gonzalez-how-can-i-insert-multiple-rows-each-of-w).